# get returned value from function which is inside class

Tags: php, function, class, oop, return

i want take returned value from function, but i think problem caused because function is inside class.
this is class code :

```
class language{

private $dbh;



function messanger($code){


    switch ($code){
        case 1: // Home Page is not configured
    exit("<span class='sysError'>Query Error: </span><span class='sysMessage'>Please Set Home Page</span> ");
        break;


        }

}


function add($index){

$ins = $this->dbh->insert("INSERT INTO language (example) VALUES (:example)",Array(":example"=>$index));
($ins ? "" : exit(1));

}


public function show($transed = Array()){


(isset($_GET['lang']) ? $index = $_GET['lang'] : "");
(isset($_POST['lang']) ? $index = $_POST['lang'] : "");

if(isset($transed[$index]) && $transed[$index] != ""){


    return $transed[$index];

}else{

    return $transed['example'];

}



}


function take($index){

$out = $this->dbh->selectOne("SELECT * FROM language WHERE example = :example",Array(":example"=>$index));
($out ? $this->show($out) :  $this->add($index));

}




public function __construct(){

    global $connect;
    global $docRoot;
    global $startLang;

        $this->dbh = new Queryer($connect);





}




}
```

so i'm trying call this class like this :

```
$lang = new language;
echo $lang->take("name");
echo $lang->take("last name");
```

in action function named "take" calls function named "show", and in function show as you see i have return statesman, but echo can't get this return value, if i will change return statesman with echo  it works but i need return, why return does not works?

Comment: You have to `return` one of these `$this->show($out)` or `$this->add($index));` on this line `($out ? $this->show($out) :  $this->add($index));`

Comment: Or you can make a variable like `public $tVal;` then in the `show()` method do `$this->tVal = (!empty($transed[$index]))? $transed[$index] : $transed['example'];` Then in your `take()` method `return $this->tVal;` or return `$this` for a method chain: `echo $lang->take("name")->tVal;`

Comment: Did you already solve the problem?

Comment: yes i used solution that told me Rasclatt, i defined public variable and after i chained from function echo $lang->take("name")->tVal; like this

Comment: Rasclatt yesterday add your comment in answer and i will mark as correct answer